How do I fix this IOS bundling failure? Unable to resolve "@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault" from "node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js"
(https://i.sstatic.net/4P97j1Lj.png)
What can I do? I've tried to delete and reinstall node_packages. Here's my package.json:
{
  "name": "optimeal",
  "main": "App.js",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "reset-project": "node ./scripts/reset-project.js",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "lint": "expo lint"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/metro-config": "^0.18.11",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "expo": "^51.0.37",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.28",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.9",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.23",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.7",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~51.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}

I tried to run npx expo start and i've tried to debug by deleting the node_modules and npm install.

How do you create the project?
Which node version are you using?
